# R - ggplot2 - plots and aes depending on multiple variables creates zigzag despite monotone data

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, melt

I am given a table of prices depending on the year and various parameters.

```
structure(list(Year = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), guar = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02), 
vol = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2), fee = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02), value = c(103.490219783939, 104.64694534429, 
105.423021866961, 106.003997632507, 103.987761167674,      105.637197779702, 
106.901255344043, 107.965567455406, 102.953065656004, 103.545441115507, 
103.741845779355, 103.732177003242, 103.490219783939, 104.64694534429, 
105.423021866961, 106.003997632507, 102.460474891754, 102.574796992078, 
102.307300703979, 101.84752143324, 103.036847936938, 103.785353707651, 
104.185436261084, 104.417467321901, 107.438302065026, 110.172519129122, 
112.120314291466, 113.657230720516, 107.965567455406, 111.246291601828, 
113.750976986408, 115.851941887821, 106.891292109859, 109.043467438409, 
110.389127553239, 111.309322271107, 107.438302065026, 110.172519129122, 
112.120314291466, 113.657230720516, 106.369273097772, 107.990957085228, 
108.806658224208, 109.200666959571, 106.935904609248, 109.17460141814, 
110.636502202272, 111.697991480364), rate = c(0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 
0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02)), row.names = c(NA, -48L
), class = "data.frame")

    Year guar vol  fee    value rate
 1     1 0.01 0.1 0.00 103.4902 0.02
 2     2 0.01 0.1 0.00 104.6469 0.02
 3     3 0.01 0.1 0.00 105.4230 0.02
 4     4 0.01 0.1 0.00 106.0040 0.02
```

and would like now to plot this with ggplot in such a way that "year" is the x-axis, "value" gives the y-value, color depends on "guar", shape on "vol" and the graph is split in three diagramms according to "fee":

```
 ggplot(df_tot,aes(x=Year,y=value,colour=as.factor(guar),shape=as.factor(vol)))+
   geom_line()+geom_point()+ facet_wrap(as.factor(fee))
```

Yet, the resulting graphs are zig-zagging

[image]

despite the data being monotone. For example, we have

```
 > df_tot[df_tot$fee==0 & df_tot$guar==0.01 & df_tot$vol==0.1,5]
 [1] 103.4902 104.6469 105.4230 106.0040
```

Comment: There is a `~` missing in the `facet_wrap` call, it should look like `facet_wrap(~as.factor(fee))`. I'm not sure how that could cause your problem, but once I add the tilde, the exact code you provide here plots correctly. Maybe you have a package loaded that masks `ggplot2::facet_wrap`?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the example, got an error.

I changed the facet for `facet_wrap(~as.factor(fee))` and got the following:

```
ggplot(df_tot,
       aes(x=Year,y=value,colour=as.factor(guar),shape=as.factor(vol)))+
  geom_line()+geom_point() + facet_wrap(as.factor(fee))
```

[image]